# need to parse Json string using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I have my json value coming from java, as

```
var obj = "[{"id":"58","str":"sd <p/> Comment By Smith John on 2012-10-30"},{"id":"58","str":"sd <p/> Comment By Smith John on 2012-10-30"},{"id":"58","str":"sd <p/> Comment By Smith John on 2012-10-30"},{"id":"58","str":"sd <p/> Comment By Smith John on 2012-10-30"},{"id":"58","str":"sd <p/> Comment By Smith John on 2012-10-30"},{"id":"58","str":"sd <p/> Comment By Smith John on 2012-10-30"},{"id":"58","str":"sd <p/> Comment By Smith John on 2012-10-30"},{"id":"58","str":"sd <p/> Comment By Smith John on 2012-10-30"}] ".
```

I want to parse using jquery as $.parseJSON(obj);

I am getting error as undefined. I want to get the id value.

I included the jquery-ui.js and jquery.js.

I checked in the jsonlint and get it as valid json.

Comment: how you are accessing the id for it... this is an array of objects can you past how you tried to access the id.

Comment: what you tried Please post that too?

Comment: Please show your JS code. If you're using one of jQuery's Ajax functions to retrieve this object (as implied by the "jquery-ajax" tag on your question) then you shouldn't need to use `$.parseJSON()` because jQuery will parse the string for you and pass the resulting object (in this case an array) to the callback function you provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript strings containing `"` characters must be either delimited by `'` character or have the `"` escaped as `\"`.

With your current code you should have errors trying to parse the JS that attempts to instantiate `obj` before it complains that `obj` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

please add the escape params for the string first like the below.

```
var obj = "[{\"id\":\"58\",\"str\":\"sd <p/> Comment By Smith John on 2012-10-30\"},{\"id\":\"58\",\"str\":\"sd <p/> Comment By Smith John on 2012-10-30\"}]"
```

and then take the parsed object to a variable and access the id in the below manner..

var tmp = $.parseJSON(obj);
 tmp[1].id;

hope you got the answer.